# ¿Cómo creo una variable binaria en base a un condicional?

Tags: r, nlp

Tengo una base de datos basada en palabras individuales extraídas de comentarios. Supongamos el siguiente ejemplo que servirá de ejemplo de lo que tengo:

| Comentario | Palabra 1 | Palabra 2 | Palabra 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Me gusta R | Me | gusta | R |
| Me gusta programar | Me | gusta | programar |
| Programar es divertido | Programar | es | divertido |

El caso es que tengo un diccionario con cada una de las palabras únicas en que se encuentran en esta matriz de palabras:

| Palabras_diccionario |
| --- |
| divertido |
| es |
| gusta |
| me |
| programar |
| R |

Y aquí viene el desafío... ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear una columna cuya variable se base en un código binario según la aparición de las palabras en el diccionario?

Mejor con un ejemplo. Basándonos en el diccionario y en la matriz creadas más arriba, la variable resultante sería la siguiente:

| Comentario | Palabra 1 | Palabra 2 | Palabra 3 | Código |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Me gusta R | Me | gusta | R | **001101** |
| Me gusta programar | Me | gusta | programar | **001110** |
| Programar es divertido | Programar | es | divertido | **110010** |

Como pueden ver, cada palabra del comentario lleva asignado un 0 o un 1 según su posición de aparición en el diccionario. El primer valor del código binario corresponde a la primera palabra del diccionario (en este caso 'divertido'). Como en el primer comentario esta palabra no aparece, en esta posición lleva asignado un 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una prueba de concepto:

```
cadena <- 'Me gusta R'
diccionario <- c('divertido', 'es', 'gusta', 'Me', 'programar', 'R')

paste0(as.numeric(!is.na(match(diccionario, strsplit(cadena, ' ')[[1]]))), collapse = "") 

[1] "001101"
```

Explicación:

- Tenemos el universo completo de palabras en `diccionario()`
- Tomamos la cadena a analizar y la separamos en palabras con `strsplit`
- Con `match()` y partiendo del diccionario ubicamos las posiciones de cada palabra dentro de la cadena, las que no encontramos serán `NA`
- Luego simplemente, chequeamos, los `NA` serán 0 y los `!NA`, 1.
- Por último concatenamos todo en una cadena.

Puedes implementar esto para procesar tu columna así:

```
cadena <- c('Me gusta R', 'Me gusta programar', 'Programar es divertido')
sapply(cadena, FUN=function(x) {
  paste0(as.numeric(!is.na(match(diccionario, strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]))), collapse = "")
}
)

          Me gusta R 
              "001101" 
    Me gusta programar 
              "001110" 
Programar es divertido 
              "110000"
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchísimas gracias por tu solución.

Comment: Hola Patricio, ¿Es posible que en el diccionario aparezca una segunda columna indicando la frecuencia de aparición de cada palabra?

Comment: Si, es posible, deberías contar las apariciones por palabra, no es complejo, te sugiero que lo plantees en una nueva pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Patricio, ¿Me podrías decir cómo generar los códigos con los que me ayudaste pero partiendo de que las palabras ya están separadas en columnas? Mi dataframe ya tiene una columna para cada palabra (Palabra_1, Palabra_2,..., Palabra_n). De como que necesito un código que genere un número binario según si hace match el  Diccionario con las columnas en las que están las palabras separadas. Espero haberme explicado. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola @user305452, ¿de casualidad es esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567648/c%c3%b3mo-a%c3%b1adir-columna-con-frecuencias-a-un-diccionario-de-valores-%c3%banicos ?

Comment: Hola Patricio: Sí y no. Me explico:

Gracias a esa pregunta he creado un diccionario con las palabras que NO me interesa tratar. Como ya he separado las frases en una columna para cada palabra, he podido convertir en NA las palabras que NO quiero que aparezcan.

De este modo, ahora quiero generar con el diccionario de las palabras que SÍ me interesan y el dataframe con las palabras que SÍ me interesan, el código binario tal y como me ayudaste la anterior vez (y de la que estoy muy agradecido).

Comment: ¿Podrías ayudarme @Patricio Moracho? Muchas gracias

Comment: A ver, si logré interpretar: tienes un data.frame con las palabras que deseas buscar, y dices que tienes otro data.frame dónde en distintas columnas tienes las palabras deseadas que quedan de la frase original, por que no concatenas estás palabras por cada fila con `paste`  y vuelves a construir una nueva frase, y ahora tienes la base para aplicar la solución de esta pregunta.