# ¿Cómo añadir columna con frecuencias a un diccionario de valores únicos?

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Tengo una matriz cuyas columnas son la separación de diferentes frases en palabras independientes. Ejemplo:

| Frase | Palabra_1 | Palabra_2 | Palabra_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texto de ejemplo | Texto | de | ejemplo |
| Frase de ejemplo | Frase | de | ejemplo |
| Palabra separada | Palabra | separada | NA |
| Gracias de antemano | Gracias | de | antemano |

a través del siguiente código:

```
dataframe %>% 
  gather(key = nombre_columna, value = Diccionario, -Frase) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Diccionario)) %>% 
  select(Diccionario) %>% 
  mutate(Diccionario = stringr::str_to_lower(Diccionario)) %>% 
  unique()
```

He conseguido sacar todos los valores únicos de mi matriz:

**Output**

```
   Diccionario
1       texto
2       frase
3     palabra
4     gracias
5          de
6    separada
7     ejemplo
8    antemano
```

Pero necesito una columna asociada a la cantidad de veces que aparece una palabra en el dataframe y, en caso de que aparezca menos de "n" veces, sea eliminada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener el conteo de palabras, debes modificar un poco tu código:

```
dataframe %>% 
 gather(key = nombre_columna, value = Diccionario, -Frase) %>% 
 filter(!is.na(Diccionario)) %>% 
 mutate(Diccionario = stringr::str_to_lower(Diccionario)) %>% 
 count(Diccionario) %>% 
 filter(n>=3)
```

Este código crea la columna "n", que contiene el conteo de palabras. La columna filter, permite seleccionar todas aquellas filas en que la columna "n" sea mayor o igual a 3.